# Spotfire: Empty values on x-axis

Tags: charts, expression, spotfire, tibco

Spotfire question: I have a data table with monthly data that is visualized in a bar chart. I however also want to visualize the information in quarters, by showing the latest month of the quarter in the format '20Q1, 20Q2, etc.'. (So I don't want to use standard 'date format'.)

My idea was to create an additional column that is filled for March, June, Sep, Dec and empty for the other months. Then with a document property, the user can select to either view the data in months or in quarters (i.e. the last month of the quarter).
So far so good, my data now looks like this:

| Month | Value | YearQuarter |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Jan-20 | 100 |  |
| Feb-20 | 200 |  |
| Mar-20 | 400 | 20Q1 |
| Apr-20 | 125 |  |
| May-20 | 101 |  |
| Jun-20 | 300 | 20Q2 |

The problem now is that when I visualize the data with YearQuarter on the x-axis, it also shows all the (empty) values in a bucket. See below. How to solve this? Note that the x-axis has a custom expression "<$esc(${Granularity})>", where Granularity is a document property to determine what column to pick.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Did you try limiting your data with whatever expression you have put in x axis.

Thanks

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).